# How to partition the following table in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to partition and order the following table, where I have used all sorts of `row_number() over()` and `dense_rank() over()` combinations but am not getting what I need.

The MWE table is as follows:

```
Person        Visit         Last_Visit    Gap_1_yr
------        -----         --------      --------
1             01/01/2001    01/01/2000    NULL
1             01/01/2003    01/01/2001    gap
1             01/01/2004    01/01/2003    NULL
1             01/01/2006    01/01/2004    gap 
2             01/01/2005    01/01/2002    gap
2             01/01/2010    01/01/2005    gap
```

where a person turns up for an appointment, and if the persons next appointment is > 365 days from their previous appointment (I used a lag function for this).

What I want is, whenever there is a gap, I want to partition so I have the following:

```
Person        Visit         Last_Visit    Gap_1_yr     SEQ
------        -----         --------      --------     ---
1             01/01/2001    01/01/2000    NULL         1
1             01/01/2003    01/01/2001    gap          2
1             01/01/2004    01/01/2003    NULL         2
1             01/01/2006    01/01/2004    gap          3
2             01/01/2005    01/01/2002    gap          1
2             01/01/2010    01/01/2005    gap          2
```

You see that when there is a gap, the sequence iterates by one until the next gap - all per person.

I have tried:

```
row_number() over(partition by person order by gap)
```

but this iterates for every cell in SEQ until finding a new person -ignores gaps

and have tried:

```
dense_rank() over(partition by person order by gap)
```

returns 1's in every cell in SEQ

```
dense_rank() over(partition by person,gap order by gap)
```

also returns all 1's.

does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `gap` to a flag.  Then use `sum()` to do a cumulative sum of the flag:

```
select mwe.*,
       sum(case when gap_1_yr = 'gap' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by person order by visit)
          ) as seq
from mwe;
```

Comment: genius. so simple and does the job